# Extjs ComboBox - Change the CSS?

Tags: html, css, extjs, combobox

I need to display a dropdown (coded in Extjs ComboBox), but it should look like a table as shown in the below picture.
Can this be done by modifying or overwriting the CSS?

I appreciate the help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it's not possible using CSS alone but you can use XTemplates to do something similar.

I've done it like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

        var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['class', 'desc', 'policy', 'ac'],
            data : [
                {"class":"1", "desc":"Medical Bills", "policy":"41000", "ac":"1"},
                {"class":"12", "desc":"One Time Payments", "policy":"41000", "ac":"1"},
                {"class":"3", "desc":"Treatment", "policy":"41000", "ac":"1"}
            ]
        });

        // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
    Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Class Description',
        width: 400,
        store: states,
        queryMode: 'local',
        valueField: 'class',
        displayField: 'desc',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listConfig: {
            minWidth: 500,
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<div class="HeaderDiv" style="width: 75px;">Class</div>' + 
                '<div class="HeaderDiv" style="width: 300px;">Description</div>' +
                '<div class="HeaderDiv" style="width: 95px;">Policy</div>'+
                '<div class="HeaderDiv" style="width: 20px;">A/C</div>' +
                '<ul style="list-style-type: none;"><tpl for=".">' + 
                '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item" style="list-style-type: none;"> ' + 
                    '<div class="InnerDiv" style="width: 75px;">{class}</div>' +
                    '<div class="InnerDiv" style="width: 300px;">{desc}</div>' + 
                    '<div class="InnerDiv" style="width: 95px;">{policy}</div>' + 
                    '<div class="InnerDiv" style="width: 20px;">{ac}</div>' + 
                '</li></tpl></ul>'
            )    
        }
    });
});
```

Really, it should be done using an actual table but it seems (From what I've tried anyway) that the ComboBox needs the ul/li tags in order to work correctly.

If you want to see it in action, here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MzdqJ/3/

It doesn't look to great but that should just be a case of playing around with the CSS styles. The logic should work at least.